# Tabbed Layout For Each Resource

Tags: react-admin

I'd like to change the layout for my resources, so that the page /resource-name shows a card with the tabs "List", "Create", "Edit". I managed to make it "list" under the List tab using dataProvider(), but I can't figure out how to render the Create & Edit components under the relevant tabs. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood you want to have a component with a `<TabbedShowLayout>` with tabs for list, create and edit on the route `/resource`? The route `/resource` is the one RA assumes when a component is provider in the `list` prop of `<Resource>`, so if you create a component with a `<TabbedShowLayout>` an in `<Tab>` list, put a `<List>` component, on create and `Create` component, and for edit an `Edit` component it might work for what you desire, I have not tested it. However see if is not ideal to use the props create, edit, and list of `Resource`, with them you can present data and have actions linking to one another.

Maybe your problem is in routing, since create in RA defaults to `/resource/create`, could you clarify your problem?

Comment: Oh I see. I haven't tried it with the <TabbedShowLayout> because, from what I understood from the documentation, it was meant for the <Show> component, just liked <TabbedForm> was meant for <Create> & <Edit>. 
As for the issue I had, I tried to render the <Create> component with the  "Create" tab, and I specified the name of the resource in the resource prop, but I think you may be right about the routing part since I was testing this view under /test. Thanks!

Comment: RA uses the props of `Resource` for routing, list goes to `/resource`, create goes to `/resource/create`, show to `/resource/resourceID/show` and edit to `/resource/resourceID`. After explaning the answer I notice that your problem might be about routing instead, either way, I think you should have different components for each CRUD operation, since RA doesn't support the feature you're trying to implement at the moment. Check [documention of resource](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Resource.html) for more help!

Comment: Thanks! I did check the resource docs & source code, and tried to change the routing part, but it didn't work. I'll just keep it as it is for now since it's not very important.